# Get data from Pandas DataFrame using column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [4, 2], 'num_wings': [0, 2]},
...                   index=['dog', 'hawk'])
>>> df
      num_legs  num_wings
dog          4          0
hawk         2          2
>>> for row in df.itertuples():
...     print(row)
...
Pandas(Index='dog', num_legs=4, num_wings=0)
Pandas(Index='hawk', num_legs=2, num_wings=2)
```

I am parsing an excel sheet using `pandas.DataFrame.itertuples` which will give me a `pandas.DataFrame` over each iteration. Consider the `pandas.DataFrame` returned in each iteration as shown above.

Now off the each data frame `Pandas(Index='dog', num_legs=4, num_wings=0)` I would like to access the values using the keyword `num_legs` however upon using the same I get the below exception.

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Could someone help on how to retrieve the data from the data frames using the column headers directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.num_legs)
  # print(row.num_wings)   # Other column values

# Output
4
2
```

Comment: accepting this since I was using itertuples to iterate over data frames.

Comment: I tried to use the same when reading a csv using `read_csv` however my first row after comments in csv is not being treated as column names and I get exception while using `row["columnHeader"]`

Comment: While that's a separate question which you should raise, but as a hint play with `header` argument.

Comment: Tried to use `header` argument , unfortunately the csv have extra column data apart from column header and hence upon using the `header` argument the parsing fails

Comment: @darth_coder Then I suggest you should ask a separate question, by listing only this problem with proper explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error when using a variable.

```
v = 'num_legs'
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row[v])

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

To use `df.itertuples()` and use the attribute name as a variable.

```
v = 'num_legs'
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(getattr(row, v))
```

At the end `df.itertuples()` is faster than `df.iterrows()`.

Comment: How did you evaluated to conclude that `itertuples` is faster than `iterrows` ?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/#looping-with-itertuples-and-iterrows) and last week I have tested the same with large dataframes.

Comment: And also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues)

Answer (score 1):

you could use `iterrows()`,

```
for u,row in df.iterrows():
    print(u)
    print (row)
    print (row['num_legs'])
```

O/P:

```
dog
num_legs     4
num_wings    0
Name: dog, dtype: int64
4
hawk
num_legs     2
num_wings    2
Name: hawk, dtype: int64
2
```

Comment: This answer is also correct and I would now use `iterrows` while coding rather than `itertuples` since the way data is accessed mimics array index operator.